# (git-log) The returned results are different even though I used the same command on same branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-log

I'm using git log to show commit log (files changed, lines added, lines deleted) on a branch with the command below that contains filters:

`git log --shortstat --author="cuongnq|hung.nguyen|thinhnv" --since="2018-03-26" --until="2018-04-12" --no-merges | grep -E "fil(e|es) changed" | awk '{files+=$1; inserted+=$4; deleted+=$6; delta+=$4-$6; ratio=deleted/inserted} END {printf "Commit stats:\n- Files changed (total).. %s\n- Lines added (total).... %s\n- Lines deleted (total).. %s\n- Total lines (delta).... %s\n- Add./Del. ratio (1:n).. 1 : %s\n", files, inserted, deleted, delta, ratio }'`

I used that command in the morning but in the afternoon the returned result is different. I dont understand. Can anyone explain this issue and how to fix it?

The retured result in the morning:

- Files changed (total).. 1258
- Lines added (total).... 59519
- Lines deleted (total).. 8714
- Total lines (delta).... 50805
- Add./Del. ratio (1:n).. 1 : 0.146407

And in the afternoon:

- Files changed (total).. 1271
- Lines added (total).... 59761
- Lines deleted (total).. 8953
- Total lines (delta).... 50808
- Add./Del. ratio (1:n).. 1 : 0.149813

Thank in advance!

Comment: What does it return? What exactly are the differences?

Comment: Hi @kowsky, 
the result in the morning:
- Files changed (total).. 1258
- Lines added (total).... 59519
- Lines deleted (total).. 8714
- Total lines (delta).... 50805
- Add./Del. ratio (1:n).. 1 : 0.146407

and In the afternoon: 
- Files changed (total).. 1271
- Lines added (total).... 59761
- Lines deleted (total).. 8953
- Total lines (delta).... 50808
- Add./Del. ratio (1:n).. 1 : 0.149813